# ODP.NET Managed Driver Performance Counters missing in perfmon

Tags: odp.net, performancecounter, odp.net-managed

How do I enable the performance counters for ODP.NET Managed Driver in perfom in order to be able to monitor them? Currently I am unable to see the category "Oracle Data Provider for .NET" in perfmon at all.

I've tried to register the counters from within the configure script int the xcopy installation bundle (ODP.NET_Managed121010.zip), but the relevant part ended with an error:

OraProvCfg /action:register /product:odpm /component:perfcounter /providerpath:"D:\svnroot\tech\Nasadzovanie\Assemblies\Oracle.ManagedDataAccess\tmp\odp.net\managed\x64\..\common\Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll"
ERROR: Encountered a problem while registering ODP counters

The relevant sections of my app.config are correct I hope:

```
<configSections>
  <section name="oracle.manageddataaccess.client"
           type="OracleInternal.Common.ODPMSectionHandler,
                 Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.121.1.0,
                 Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
</configSections>
<oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
  <version number="*">
    <settings>
      <setting name="PerformanceCounters" value="4095" />
    </settings> 
  </version>
</oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
```

Comment: run as admin and try

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the app config settings mentioned above, you need to run the following command as 'Administrator'. Before executing make sure to replace the {path} with the correct directory.

OraProvCfg /action:register /product:odpm /component:perfcounter /providerpath:"{path}\oracle.manageddataaccess.dll"

You can find the OraProvCfg.exe in the ODP.NET xcopy download.